# How do I get PHAsset of a video if it's still not saved to Photos?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, phasset

How can I get videos PHAsset, if I've got only a URL of it and it's still not saved, but it's already captured? Extra information: My user records a video - then I want to see a PHAsset of this video, and then he saves it. I don't want to fetch the asset after it was saved. I want to fetch it before it's saved. Thanks a lot!